# For what $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ does generalized continued fraction $x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+...}}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics, continued-fractions

For what $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ does generalized continued fraction $x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+...}}}$ converge? Being an undergraduate student knowing only information from Wikipedia on the subject, I tried to find an non-recursive formula for the sequence of convergents $x,\frac{x(x+1)}{x},\frac{x^2(x+2)}{x(x+1)},...$ but could not do so.

What approaches can one take to demonstrate convergence or divergence of this generalized continued fraction? When it converges, how can one compute the limit?

Comment: There's a recursive expression for convergents $c_{n+1} = x(1 + \frac{1}{c_n})$, if that helps

Comment: Assuming the limit $c\neq 0$ exists, would it satisfy $c=x(1+\frac{1}{c})$ by the Algebraic Limit Theorem?

Comment: If it exists, would $c$ be equal to $\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2+4x})$ for $x>0$ because the convergents are nonnegative?

Answer (score 1):

**Condition for Convergence:**

Let $k = x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+\ldots}}$.

It follows that $k = x + \frac{x}{k}$.

Solve the equation for $k$.

$$k^2-xk-x=0$$
$$k=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}$$

$k$ converges only if $x^2+4x\geq0$, i.e. $\underline{\underline{x\leq-4 \text{ or } x>0}}$.

**Limit**

When $x>0$, it is apparent that $k>0$, so $\underline{\underline{k=\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}}}$ because $x<\sqrt{x^2+4x}$.

When $x\leq-4$, suppose $k>0$. Then by observing $k=x+\frac{x}{k}$, contradiction arises because $\text{LHS}>0\text{ and RHS}<0$.

Therefore, $k<0$. And $\underline{\underline{k=\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}}}$.

Comment: How can we prove convergence?